# Usage of Jetpack Security with two master keys

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-security

Anyone had success in using Jetpack Security for encryption with two separate master keys? The use case for this is having one set of data encrypted with a "regular" key and another with a key with additional biometric protection.

Tried the following with just two separate keys with the same spec just for testing:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val firstMasterKey by lazy {
        MasterKeys.getOrCreate(provideKeyGenParameters("aliasFirst"))
    }

    private val secondMasterKey by lazy {
        MasterKeys.getOrCreate(provideKeyGenParameters("aliasSecond"))
    }

    private val firstEncryptedFile by lazy {
        EncryptedFile.Builder(
            File(filesDir, "firstFile"),
            this,
            firstMasterKey,
            EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
        )
            .build()
    }

    private val secondEncryptedFile by lazy {
        EncryptedFile.Builder(
            File(filesDir, "secondFile"),
            this,
            secondMasterKey,
            EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
        )
            .build()
    }

    private fun provideKeyGenParameters(alias: String) =
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            alias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        )
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setKeySize(256)
            .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        saveFiles()
    }

    private fun saveFiles() {
        firstEncryptedFile.openFileOutput().use {
            it.write(ByteArray(1) { Byte.MIN_VALUE })
        }

        // if I comment this save it works fine
        // as soon as I uncomment it the app crashes
        secondEncryptedFile.openFileOutput().use {
            it.write(ByteArray(1) { Byte.MIN_VALUE })
        }
    }
}
```

but got `InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)` as soon as the other key was used. This happens on both stable version and and latest alpha03.

I posted a bug report to Google about that https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192470296 but I have no hope since based on the other reported bugs they don't care at all. Anyways, if you encounter the issue please star it, maybe someone will notice.

Comment: `MasterKeys` is deprecated, according to the JavaDocs and source code. Have you tried a non-deprecated alternative?

Comment: The easiest way to solve your problem and use standard libraries is this way: 1) generate a random key (e.g. 32 bytes for AES-256), 2) encrypt your content with this key, 3) encrypt the random key with a user password/input (e.g. using PBKDF2 for key derivation, AES-GCM as encryption mode) and store the output with a tag "user input". 4) encrypt the random key secondly with some input coming from biometric stuff (e.g. AES GCM again) and store the output with a tag "biometric input". 5) clear the random key from memory. For decryption, run either the user-input or biometric input data.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes tried also the MasterKey Builder from the latest alpha - same results.

Comment: @MichaelFehr thanks for your comment, will think about this once the Jetpack solution is definitely off the table (and it seems it will be so)

Answer (score 0):

Using the updated androidx.security:security-crypto library (currently alpha06) you can do this:

```
  companion object {
    private val FIRST_KEY_ALIAS = "aliasFirst"
    private val SECOND_KEY_ALIAS = "aliasSecond"
  }
  private val firstMasterKey by lazy {
        MasterKey.Builder(context, FIRST_KEY_ALIAS)
          .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
          .build()
    }

  private val secondMasterKey by lazy {
        MasterKey.Builder(context, SECOND_KEY_ALIAS)
          .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
          .build()
    }

    private val firstEncryptedFile by lazy {
        EncryptedFile.Builder(
            File(filesDir, "firstFile"),
            this,
            firstMasterKey,
            EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
        )
         .setKeyAlias(FIRST_KEY_ALIAS) //don't forget this or it won' work
         .build()
    }

    private val secondEncryptedFile by lazy {
        EncryptedFile.Builder(
            File(filesDir, "secondFile"),
            this,
            secondMasterKey,
            EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
        )
         .setKeyAlias(SECOND_KEY_ALIAS) //don't forget this
         .build()
    }
```

Note that you need to set the key alias on both the MasterKey.Builder and the EncryptedFile.Builder or it won't work. I had this issue where it only worked if I used the same key alias for all encrypted files until I set the key alias for the encrypted file builder.